# How to send Javascript variable to PHP using Ajax on mac?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a basic code in which I am trying to send the value of an input box to PHP using ajax.

> I am sending data from try.php to books2.php.

My code for try.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post">
  <input type="number" min="0" id="Q1" name="Q1" method="post"><br>
  <input type="number" min="0" id="Q2" name="Q2" method="post"><br>
  <input type="number" min="0" id="Q3" name="Q3" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="submit2">
  </form>
<h2 id="content"></h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#submit2").click(function(){
    var q1 = $("#Q1").val()
    var q2 = $("#Q2").val()
    var q3 = $("#Q3").val()
    $.ajax({
      url:"books2.php",
      data:{"Quantity1":q1},
      success:function(data){
        $('#content').html(data)
      }

    })
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code for books2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Quantity1'])){
  echo $_POST['Quantity1'];
}else {
  echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Probably missing `type: "POST"`

Comment: Your HTML form is submitted when you click `#submit2`, and loading the server response will abort the pending AJAX call.

Comment: What is the exact question here?  What's the expected result?  What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lot of mistakes in your code.

I want to start with `;`, you missing them.

Then why you have `method="post"` at inputs?

You don't need `FORM` because it will redirect you.

Your `JQUERY` source script is not working.

When you using `POST` in your `AJAX` you have to use `POST` in your `AJAX` script.

So this is the code:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="Q1" name="Q1"><br>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="Q2" name="Q2"><br>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="Q3" name="Q3">
    <input type="submit" id="submit2">
<h2 id="content"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#submit2").click(function(){
        var q1 = $("#Q1").val();
        var q2 = $("#Q2").val();
        var q3 = $("#Q3").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"books2.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{"Quantity1":q1},
            success:function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
            }

        });
    });
```

And AJAX code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Quantity1'])){
    echo $_POST['Quantity1'];
}else {
    echo "failed";
}
```